# React higher order component returns only defaultProps with curly brace function but works with direct return function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Type 1: `const funcExample ({param1}) => (<div/>)`

Type 2: `const funcExample ({param1}) => {return (<div/>)}`

Higher order function looks like this

```
export const CHOC: HOC<*, any> = compose(
  graphql(...),
  withProps(...),
  defaultProps(...),
);

export default HOC(functionalComponent);
```

Higher order function passes the correct values to type 1 but for type 2 it only passes the defaultProps value. I would really appreciate the help!